# Vectorizing NumPy code for arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Let's say I have a function which takes as input a NumPy array `x`, and a NumPy array `a`. For instance:

```
def f(x, a): 
    """
    Compute the sum of all elements in x and the dot-product between x and a.

    Args:
        x, a: NumPy arrays.
    """
    assert len(x) == len(a) 

    return np.sum(x), np.dot(x, a)

x = np.ones(5)
a = np.ones(5)

f(x, a)
```

which all works fine. 
However, suppose now I want the function to also work when `x` is an 2-D array, by applying the sum function to each column.
I could re-write:

```
def f(x, a): 
    """
    Compute the column-sum of x and the dot-product between x and a.

    Args:
        x, a: NumPy arrays.
    """
    assert x.shape[0] == len(a) 

    return np.sum(x, axis=1), np.dot(a, x)

x = np.ones((10, 5))
a = np.ones(5)

f(x, a)
```

which would work when x is a 2-D array. 
However, the re-written function would fail when we try to apply it to `x = np.ones(5)` due to the `assert x.shape[1] ...` and the `np.sum(x, axis=1)` since the shape of `x` is `(5,)`. 
How could I make the same piece of code work for both cases?
The only way I could think of is to do an ugly check-and-reshape:

```
def f(x, a): 
    """
    Compute the column-sum of x and the dot-product between x and a.

    Args:
        x, a: NumPy arrays.
    """
    if len(x.shape == 1):
        x = x.reshape((len(x), 1))

    assert x.shape[0] == len(a) 

    return np.sum(x, axis=1), np.dot(a, x)
```

But the resulting code is neither clear nor efficient... Is there a better way to vectorize the code?

Comment: `def f(x, a, axis=None)` and then `np.sum(x, axis=axis)`

Comment: You pass the axis parameter yourself. If you don't, it defaults to `None` and it computes a global sum across all axes.

Comment: Use `x = np.atleast_2d(x)` at the start of the function code.

Comment: Dimension tests don't hurt efficiency.  Using a function like `np.atleast_2d` just hides the test in a function call (look at its code).  `numpy` functions use tests like this all the time to massage the inputs into a common expected shape.

Comment: is the assert really necessary? the dot will break if a & x are not in the right shape, ie. if `a.shape[-1] != x.shape[0]`

Comment: `axis=-1` should work with both 1d and 2d arrays (last axis).

Comment: btw, the code examples dont work unless modified

Comment: @Divakar Thanks! I wasn't aware of this.